# d3v4 timeline adding a date axis to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have refactored this timeline chart for d3v4. I am unsure though how to add dates to to the bottom to indicate the timeline.

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/179/

```
//scales
var x =  d3.scaleTime()
        .range([0, w])              
        .domain([timeBegin, timeEnd]);
```

its based on this old timeline code - but again didn't have an labelled axis. http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2338034

this example calls an axis..

https://github.com/jiahuang/d3-timeline

```
   var axis = g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + yPosition + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
    };
```

is this a sound solution?

```
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + (margin.top + (itemHeight + itemMargin) * maxStack) + ")")
    .attr(timeAxisTickFormat.stroke, timeAxisTickFormat.spacing)
    .call(xAxis.tickFormat("").tickSize(-(margin.top + (itemHeight + itemMargin) * (maxStack - 1) + 3), 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

In D3 we normally call `axis` the variable referring to the axis generator, not to the group that contains it. Other than that, this is indeed the most common way to call the axis:

```
var gX = chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + 140 + "," + 450 + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

Here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yqkz1z5/

PS: change the magic numbers in the translate function accordingly.

Comment: Cheers @Gerardo Furtado -- I've taken it out of the each loop -- http://jsfiddle.net/5yqkz1z5/2/